# App Crashes when it's running from .ipa file but building on Xcode is working perfectly?

Tags: ios, xcode

Any solution?

> Thread 0 name:Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean the derived data of xcode and then create the ipa.